# PHP max_input_variables can't be increase

Tags: php, wordpress, file-manager

So, I tried to use user.ini file to increase my max input time into 150.

I can add any variables like upload_max_filesize = 256M; and post_max_size = 256M; But after adding the max_input_time = 150; it only display this: ARRAY(0x27c2560)

What does this ARRAY(0x27c2560) means?? and beside my max_input_time is still 60 even after save the file...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of a syntax mistake.

You said you added the following:

```
max_input_time = 150;
```

But it should be

```
max_input_time = 150
```

without any **semicolon**. And the same goes for all other modification.

Answer (score 0):

Note `;` can only be used if you want to make any comments in the `.ini` file

The error you got might be due to a syntax error in your user.ini file.

As you have used `;` for ending the statements .You should remove any `;` from the ending of statement and to apply the changes restart the PHP service or the web server.

```
; without semicolon
max_input_time = 150
```